# Select DISTINCT of a column, but have other columns returned normally

Tags: php, sql, distinct

My issue is fairly simple to explain:

I need a query which selects the DISTINCT for a column, but I need to select other columns too, normally without DISTINCT. Can anyone show me such a query as an example?

It should be an universal query!

Thanks.

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ' . DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE . " 
        $sql_where 
        ORDER BY payment_status ASC, user_id ASC";
```

I need to make this query select other stuff too, not just user_id distinct, I also need to select: donation_id, payment_status, pending_reason, txn_id, mc_gross and amount.

Sample table:

```
donation_id    user_id    mc_gross    payment_status    txn_id (has UNIQUE index)
1              4          5.00        Completed         g54g4
2              5          10.00       Pending           54yhh
3              4          6.00        Pending           54yhg
4              7          15.00       Completed         fdhgf
```

The query should return:
DISTINCT for user_id, SUM of mc_gross for the *distinct-ed* user_id, latest payment_status (would return Pending for user_id = 4).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the data you have, and the query output you desire?

Comment: Why don't explain what your requirements is rather than what you need the query to do.  I don't think DISTINCT is your answer.  It's sounding like you want more a group by aggregation.

Comment: What is a "universal query"?  What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff By universal query I mean that the query shouldn't be limited to one DBMS only. I am using MySQL.

Comment: @dispake Distinct is working fine and it serves me how it should, but I need to extend this query to select more.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  What happens if a user_id has more than one donation?  If there is only going to be one row per user_id in the output, which donation row should contribute the values for donation_id, payment_status, etc?

Comment: The last one. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: I'm assuming your donation table has user_id, donation_id, etc.  And that each user could have multiple donations.  How do you expect to return a single row from that data?  Sample data would really be helpful here as it's still unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You also need to mention how you distinguish a donation as 'the last one'

Comment: So, what is the logic to determine the last donation?  Is only one donation in a particular status?  Is there a date field?  Is donation id a guaranteed increasing integer number?  Please be aware that there's no natural order in SQL databases, so you need to have some way to determine, from your data, what the "last" record is.

Comment: How do you identify "latest"? There is timestamp column?

Comment: I am sorry I was unclear with my question, but now I explained it the best way I could.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No there is no timestamp column, latest donation has the largest donation_id number. It auto increments.

Comment: Please post the table structure, its easier to understand what you want and what can be done if we get a better view of the data structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select t1.user_id, 
       t1.donation_id, 
       t1.payment_status, 
       t1.pending_reason,
       t1.txn_id, 
       t2.sum_gross, 
       t1.amount
from the_table t1
join (
   select max(donation_id) as max_id, 
          sum(mc_gross) as sum_gross,
          user_id
   from the_table
   group by user_id
) t2 on t2.max_id = t1.donation_id
    and t2.user_id = t1.user_id;
```

Comment: Can you explain where we get the SUM for mc_gross?

Comment: @Dugi: nowhere :) I did not see that requirement. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select T2.USER_ID, T2.TOTAL_MC_GROSS, T2.LAST_DONATION_ID, 
T1.PAYMENT_STATUS, T1.TXN_ID, T1.PENDING_REASON   from
MY_TABLE T1 inner join
(
select USER_ID, SUM(MC_GROSS) AS TOTAL_MC_GROSS , 
MAX(DONATION_ID) AS LAST_DONATION_ID
from MY_TABLE 
group by USER_ID
) 
T2
on T1.DONATION_ID = T2.DONATION_ID
```